# Copy the Entire SharePoint Online Site Collection to another Office 365 Tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection, migration

I've developed a Site Collection for one client of mine (custom pages, webparts, lists, libraries modified master pages, customized settings, custom people groups, SPD workflows etc.).

Now I have another client that requires the completely same Site Collection (another branch of the company) on another Office 365 tenant.

I am wondering what would be the best way of migrating everything as it is, so I don't lose any of the data/configuration.

I had a look [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938033(v=office.15).aspx) and [HERE](http://blog.ciaops.com/2013/07/using-site-template-with-new-site.html), but I am not 100% sure if that will migrate everything.

Could somebody please advise me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Gintas, Save site as a template will help but not satisfy your requirements, so I suggest to use a 3rd party tool like share gate to can achieve that.

Comment: Hi @M.Qassas, thanks for a tip! I've done some more research on this now and it looks like it should work fine with the site template. The only issue is that groups and permissions are not migrated, but I could fix those manually... I will give it a go and see what happens :)

Comment: @M.Qassas, I have come across another issue. The Publishing feature was activated on my site and apparently you can't save publishing sites as template... Even if you switch the feature off.

Comment: This is what I feared deactivating the publishing feature not mean you will be able to save site as template :( let me check at my side if I can found anything can help

Comment: Exact same issue here. Option to Save Site as Template is gone. I need to copy a current prod site collection onto the new QA/Dev one and cant find any options at all.

Comment: Third-party tool is probably best. Migrating in SharePoint Online has to be done declaratively in code. This is different from SharePoint Server where entire sites can be easily migrated using schema, or by doing a content database migration. If you are good a SharePoint programming, then you could use the PnP site provisioning examples to copy sites programmatically. See: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/articles/pnp-provisioning-engine-and-the-core-library.md

Comment: Hi will the new SharePoint Migration tool achieve this? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introducing-the-SharePoint-Migration-Tool-9c38f5df-300b-4adc-8fac-648d0215b5f7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: The Sharepoint migration tool is a light weight version intended for assisting migration from file shares and on prem. It can, in its current version, not be used for migrating from one Site Collection to another

Answer (score 1):

you can use `save as template` but what happens, you  can't save master page as template if it is the main page  of the site.

So, to copy the Entire Online SharePoint Site Collection to another Office 365 Tenant.

You can use 3rd party tools like,

- Sharegate ([Link](https://support.share-gate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000597507-Copy-Site-Collections))
- Power shell ([Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b0d4f254-4e02-40ee-b2dd-fea2707d2cfb/migrate-site-collection-from-sharepoint-online-to-online-using-powershell?forum=sharepointadmin))
- metalogix ([Link](https://www.metalogix.com/help/Content%20Matrix%20Console/SharePoint%20Edition/002_HowTo/003_MigrationActions/004_CopySiteCollection.htm)), etc.,
- but this tools are depends on cost.

By using this tools you can achieve migrating total site collection to another farm or office 365.

Better use `sharegate` tools it will easy to use just drag and drop you get the solution.