# Duplicate my Communication modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration

We have a live communication modern site, and i want to duplicate this site and all its content into a test site so i can test things before modifying the live. so is this possible inside SharePoint online? or are there any free tools to achieve this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Copy the Entire SharePoint Online Site Collection to another Office 365 Tenant](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/212079/copy-the-entire-sharepoint-online-site-collection-to-another-office-365-tenant)

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best option is using the [PnP Provisioning Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/pnp-provisioning-framework).  This framework was initially started as a better approach to templating, intending to replace the classic web templates and site definitions, but has grown into much more.

Although there are numerous options that I won't cover here, a basic script using the Provisioning Framework in [PnP-PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) would look something like this:

```
$sourceConn = Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/site1 -UseWebLogin -ReturnConnection
$destConn = Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/site2 -UseWebLogin -ReturnConnection

Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out template.pnp -connection $sourceConn

Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path template.pnp -connection $destConn
```

Comment: thanks for the usful reply. but will this code affect the source list by any mean? i do not think so, is this correct? so is it safe to perform on a live site?

Comment: The 'Get' function will affect nothing but the file you output to.  The 'Apply' function, however, if done to an already in-use site could wreak havoc.  So be very careful where you apply it.

Comment: i tried your appraoch but i got this error `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out template.pnp -connection $sourceConn` on `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out template.pnp -connection $sourceConn`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the `Connect-PnPOnline` needs to have the ` -ReturnConnection` if you need to save the connection in a variable, your two `$..conn` objects were probably both null.  I edited the answer to show those parameters.
Also, you generally have to be a site collection admin of the sites you are connecting to to use the provisioning cmdlets.