# I am looking for a sharepoint migration tool to migrate custom sharepoint online publishing site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I am looking for a sharepoint migration tool to migrate custom sharepoint online publishing site which has custom codes, power automate workflows and master pages. Please advise.

Can anyone guide me with powershell scripts to migrate sharepoint online to another SPO?

Comment: Our tenant use ShareGate.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a tool for this migration, but most tools can't migrate power automate, to the best of my knowledge.  ShareGate or Quest / Metalogix are some of the most popular out there for SharePoint.

Comment: Can metalogix or sharegate migrate custom webparts, custom webpages as it is on the source site?

Answer (score 0):

You can use save as template but what happens, you can't save master page as template if it is the main page of the site.

So, to copy the Entire Online SharePoint Site Collection to another Office 365 Tenant.

For more information you could refer to:
[Copy the Entire SharePoint Online Site Collection to another Office 365 Tenant](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/212079/copy-the-entire-sharepoint-online-site-collection-to-another-office-365-tenant?rq=1)