# SPO Modern - Save site as template is missing and not showing

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, content-migration, save, site-design

**Requirements:**

I have a SharePoint online Modern site that is around 40 GB. I would like to save the site as a template including its design content and use the same site template on a different tenant.

**I am aware of the Site template limit that is 50 MB and cannot be changed.**

**Problem:**

I have enabled the custom script by using powershell based on the below blog post:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/08/sharepoint-online-save-list-as-template-missing.html

However, even after 3 days the "Save site as template" is still missing from the site settings knowing that It should appear since the custom script is already enabled.

The only thing that I want from the Site is the design content because I don't want to re-build the design content on the destination tenant.

Additionally, I used the https://mover.io/ app migration tool but it seems that it only migrates files from one tenant to another without taking into consideration the design content.

Could you please advise what will be the solution to export the design content of the site and apply it to an SPO modern site that is on a different tenant?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Best regards,

SmithBZ

Answer (score 4):

Modern Sites do not support the feature you're looking for. This is a complex topic, but Microsoft outlines the process for [creating templates](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy the Entire SharePoint Online Site to another Office 365 Tenant.

You can use 3rd party tools likes,

- **Sharegate ([Link](https://migration-tool.sharegate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000597507-Copy-Site-Collections))**
- **metalogix ([Link](https://www.quest.com/metalogix/))**, etc.,

By using this tools you can achieve migrating total site collection to another farm or office 365. Better use `sharegate` tools it will easy to use just drag and drop you get the solution.

Reference:

- [Copy the Entire SharePoint Online Site Collection to another Office
  365 Tenant](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/212079/copy-the-entire-sharepoint-online-site-collection-to-another-office-365-tenant)